# how to use @future method in interface triggerhandler class

Tags: trigger

```
Public interface Triggerhandler{

 void OnBeforeInsert(List<object> newobjects);
 @future
 void OnAfterInsert(Set<Id> newSetId);

}
```

unable to save this class keep getting the following error
Compile Error Expecting } but was @

can anyone pls tell me what am i doin wrong

Comment: Consider calling a future method from your interface implementation classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include annotations in an interface. Further, future methods must be static, but interface methods must be instance methods. In addition, you also cannot pass in complex data types to a future method, only primitive types and collections thereof are allowed. Probably the best option would be to create a generic Queueable class instead:

```
public interface TriggerHandler {
  void beforeInsert();
  void afterInsert();
  ...
}

public class TriggerQueueable implements Queueable {
  TriggerHandler job;
  public static void executeTriggerHandler(TriggerHandler newJob) {
    job = newJob;
    System.enqueueJob(this);
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    job.afterInsert();
  }
}
```

The exact implementation details will depend on what you need it to do, but the main point here is that you need to use Queueable to make something flexible like this.